# float higher accuracy, is it possible?

Tags: c, floating-point

How to print (with fprint) higher accuracy float (or other format). For example sqrt(5)=2.236067977543598.... I want get 100 numbers after point. It's possible?

Thank you!

Comment: No, it's not possible, floats simply don't *have* that much accuracy. You need another solution with provides "infinite" precision.

Comment: With long or double long?

Comment: You need to employ one of the special libraries for big numbers, for example on OS X it would be vBigNum.h in vecLib, in the accelerate framework, which handles as many as 300 significant figures.  There should be similar libraries on other platforms as well.  Alternatively you can define your own class of big numbers and explicitly treat the precisions.   Of course you can always just switch to a program that can do it, like Mathematica.

Comment: You can probably develop an algorithm to print 100 digits after the point, but they would be meaningless because `float` has many fewer significant (binary) digits. You might want to take a look at a high precision math library such as the [GNU MP Bignum Library](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: @user3050096: Neither `double` nor `long double` will give you 100 digits of precision.  The best you can get with current native float types will be between 33 to 36 digits of precision (quad precision, 128-bit type).

Comment: Depends on whether the 100 digits after the point have to be accurate. Number of decimals is precision, accuracy is how close said number is to desired result. Native floating points can't get near your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an infinite number of decimal places (or as much memory has your operating system will let you use) can be generated using the GMP library. http://gmplib.org/ There are variants of this library,http://www.mpfr.org/

To understand why there are only a finite number of digits with double precision floating point you need to understand how floating point numbers are represented in a computer.

http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/DataRepresentation.html (Scroll to section 4.0)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just print the result, rather than to use it in any other way, then one approach is to use the Spigot algorithm.

It's well documented here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

The floating point format uses 32 bits to store a number, the precision is limited.
(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985 for more information)

If this precision is really important, you could consider **arbitrary precision**.
(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic )

Answer (score 0):

I think Fixed-precision floating point types, which are natively supported by your CPU's floating point unit ie, float, double are not optimal for any calculation that needs many digits of precision.

You can use the [Arbitrary-precision arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)

Comment: I need to found this http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/5/c/b/5cbcf60ed41db84a242295015ffd94cd.png its possible?

Comment: I think you can use the Qfloats have a precision of 350 bits, approx 100 digits.

Comment: @user3050096 You can't really rely on the golden section formula to compute sqrt(5) using Fibonnacci since you'll still hit precision issues.

Comment: @user3050096:- You can use a third party library, such as GNU MP http://gmplib.org/